# Boot's cmdline.txt and config.txt files changed after install new package in rasbian at pi zero (USB OTG Connection)

Tags: usb, ssh, linux

I am using raspberry zero with USB OTG to my linux LMDE based [this instruction](https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb) , so when i install something like lcd 5inch driver, the files which changed in the boot's SD card folder. and the files **config.txt** changed to this:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=7
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
```

without the `dtoverlay=dwc2` text in this file.

and the file **cmdline.txt** is this kind:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait  fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
```

and the `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` text in file has been deleted.

And the **ssh** file in boot folder also deleted.

SO this happened many times when i want to update the rasbian OS or install new package via USB OTG Connection to my PC (Linux LMDE), and this files changed .

why this happened?

thanks.

Comment: What are the commands do you use to update the Raspbian OS and to install new package?

Comment: it is happened by different condition, sometimes by `apt-get update` or by installing `lcd driver` from git-hub.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get update` does not touch `/boot/cmdline.txt` and `boot/config.txt` if you use the default Raspbian repositories. So it must be the driver (what driver?) from github (where from github?). The appended settings

```
fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
```

to cmdline.txt also indicate that this is from a display driver. It may also be possible the driver checks on every boot if it has its settings in the two system files and correct them if not. So you should look at the driver installation what it is doing.

You don't tell us if the modified files are a problem for you. It is possible that the display driver need this settings and everything is good.